# How can i get the aws volumes available size by boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```
#/usr/bin/python
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
instance = ec2.Instance('i-xxxxxx')
volumes = instance.volumes.all()
print volumes
```

The answer I got `ec2.Instance.volumesCollection(ec2.Instance(id='i-xxxxxx'), ec2.Volume)`

It just list the volume total size and `status(available,in-use...)`, how can i get it?

Comment: Please update question which which programming language you are using, where your code in running etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using **Python 2.7**:

```
for volume in volumes:
  print volume.size, volume.state
```

**Output**

```
16 in-use
500 in-use
```

For other attributes:

```
dir(volume)
```

> [u'attach_to_instance', u'attachments',
>   u'availability_zone', u'create_snapshot', u'create_tags',
>   u'create_time', u'delete', u'describe_attribute', u'describe_status',
>   u'detach_from_instance', u'enable_io', u'encrypted',
>   'get_available_subresources', u'id', u'iops', u'kms_key_id', 'load',
>   'meta', u'modify_attribute', 'reload', u'size', u'snapshot_id',
>   u'snapshots', u'state', u'tags', u'volume_id', u'volume_type']

Comment: but the volume.size is the total size, which key can get the available size?

Comment: Think about it. What the SDK/API can get is the information available at the hypervisor level. Only the Total size (and other such info) is available at the hypervisor. The OS will know the available size . Can you see the available size in AWS console? No.